# Message Alert Tone

Tags: java, android

I am working on an App that gets sms alerts and would like to control volume of alert tone based on device volume. How do I adjust alert notification sound in alignment with device master volume. Following code doesn't change volume of alert in my app based on device volume.  Thank you.

```
    volume = audioMan.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
     mPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a code as per requirement as shown below.Here I have used it for Notification purpose kindly call the required on it.

Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.anyimage, "New Alert, Click Me!", System.currentTimeMillis());
 notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;